# Estoy Intentando hacer un programa que de clicks automaticos en una cordenada, pero solo me funciona una vez

Tags: java

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para realizar clicks en una ventana especifica en una cordenada especifica y me ah salido biien, hace su funcion, pero el problema esque solo lo hace una vez, coge la cordenada, realiza los clicks, y luego para, pero ya no funciona mas, se que java destruye los objetos una vez usados, asique puede ser la posible respuesta, pero como podria hacer para que sea infinito, es decir una vez que pare pueda volver a poner cordenadas y activarlo y desactivarlo, alguien sabe, porfavor.

```
 package utoclicker;

 import java.awt.AWTException;

import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import utoclicker.Codigo.EventoDeTeclado;

public class Codigo extends JFrame {

JLabel labelcords;
JLabel labelcords2;
boolean cliking = true;


public Codigo() {
    
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setTitle("Autoclick");
    componentes();
    
    EventoDeTeclado tecla = new EventoDeTeclado();
    addKeyListener(tecla);
    
    
   teclado5 tecla1 = new teclado5();
   addKeyListener(tecla1);
   
   teclado2 tecla2 = new teclado2();
   addKeyListener(tecla2);
   
   
   
   
    
}


public void componentes() {
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("X");
    label1.setBounds(70, 50, 10, 30);
    panel.add(label1);
    
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Y");
    label2.setBounds(190, 50, 10, 30);
    panel.add(label2);
    
    /*JTextArea texto1 = new JTextArea();
    
    texto1.setBounds(50, 80 ,70 ,20 );
    panel.add(texto1);
    texto1.setEditable(false);
    
    JTextArea texto2 = new JTextArea();
    
    texto2.setBounds(165, 80 ,70 ,20 );
    panel.add(texto2);
    texto2.setEditable(false);
    
    
    JTextArea texto3 = new JTextArea("1");
    
    texto3.setBounds(40, 200 ,200 ,20 );
    panel.add(texto3);
    texto3.setEditable(false);*/
    
    EventoDeTeclado tecla = new EventoDeTeclado();
    panel.addKeyListener(tecla);
    
        Point punto=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        int x=punto.x;
        int y=punto.y;
        String x1 = Integer.toString(x);
        String y1 = Integer.toString(y);
        
        
         labelcords = new JLabel();
        
        labelcords.setBounds(190, 100, 30, 30);
        labelcords.setText(x1);
        panel.add(labelcords);
        
        
         labelcords2 = new JLabel();
        
        labelcords2.setBounds(50, 100, 30, 30);
        labelcords2.setText(y1);
        panel.add(labelcords2);
        
        
        
    
    
    
    
}






public  class EventoDeTeclado implements KeyListener{
    

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  {
        
        
        
  
    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        
        
        
    }


}

public  class teclado2 implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        

        
  
}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        
        
        
    }


}


public  class teclado5 implements KeyListener{

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

        
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F3){
            
            
            Point punto=MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            int x=punto.x;
            int y=punto.y;
            String x1 = Integer.toString(x);
            String y1 = Integer.toString(y);
            
            labelcords.setText(x1);
            labelcords2.setText(y1);
            
            }
        
        
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F1){
                
               
            String x = labelcords.getText();
            String y = labelcords2.getText();
            
            int x1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
            int y1 = Integer.parseInt(y);
               
               Robot robot;
                try {
                    robot = new Robot();
                    robot.mouseMove(x1, y1);
                    robot.delay(100);
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    
                } catch (AWTException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                       
          }  
        
        
        else if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_F2){
                
               
             cliking = false;
                     
                
                    
                    Robot robot;
                    try {
                        robot = new Robot();
                        
                    } catch (AWTException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }           
        }
        
        
        
        
                            
    
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        
        
        
        
        
    }


}
```

}

Comment: No es cosa de destruir objetos... es que en ningún momento estás creando un bucle para que haga más clicks... solo uno. Si quieres más clicks, usa un bucle por ejemplo: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ /*Aquí haces el click*/};` así harías 10 clicks... O con : `while(clicking){/*haz click aquí*/};` así haría click de manera infinita hasta que pongas `clicking` a false.

Comment: pero la cosa, es que lo tengo a traves de keyevents, entonces se activa cuando presionas F1, y el problema esque solo me reconoce el keyevent una vez.

Comment: y con F2 desactivo los clicks, y lo que quiero esque cuando presione F1, vuelva a geneerar cliks